# Изменить цвет заголовка в FlexDataGrid

Tags: java, android

Добрый день. Использую в своей программе визуальный элемент управления FlexDataGrid. Мне нужно изменить цвет заголовка одного столбца. У заголовков столбцов данного грида есть поле:

public Array headerColors;

Это поле должно содержать массив цветов для градиентной заливки заголовка. Как видно тип свойства Reflection Array. В самом классе, в котором это поле находится оно никак не инициализируется. По идее как-то должно присваиваться значение этому полю. Но я не пойму как это сделать.

Подскажите пожалуйста как присвоить массив int[] этому полю? Или возможно можно как-то иначе изменить цвет заголовка одного столбца в FlexDataGrid?

Comment: что за FlexDataGrid, библиотека какая то? если да, то укажите ссылку на эту библиотеку

Comment: FlexDataGrid - это платный визуальный элемент управления. Сайт, на котором можно скачать trial-версию: http://www.flexicious.com/

Comment: Если вы купили какой-то продукт у компании, то за поддержкой логично обращаться в саппорт этой компании. Сомневаюсь, что многие со stackoverflow.ru пользовались этим продуктом.